# Redirect 301 com web.config

Tags: redirecionamento, web.config

Estou atualizando um site, e as URLs vão mudar. Então, preciso fazer um redirecionamento `301` com `web.config`, mas não consegui. Abaixo o código que montei:

```
<configuration>
    <location path="site-antigo">
        <system.webServer>
            <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="site-novo" httpResponseStatus="Permanent" />
        </system.webServer>
    </location>
</configuration>
```

O que eu esperava que ocorresse com esse código:

Ao acessar a página http://meusite.com.br/site-antigo o usuário seria redirecionado para http://meusite.com.br/site-novo, mas isso não está acontecendo. Estou fazendo algo errado?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neste caso vc deve precisar usar o [url rewrite module](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module).

```xml
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Redirect from blog">
      <match url="^site-antigo" />
      <action type="Redirect" url="site-novo" redirectType="Found" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: Mas tem o mesmo efeito de um redirect 301? O Google entende isso?

Comment: [Segundo consta na documentação, sim.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module/_static/image21.jpg) Mas sugiro confirmar no console do navegador, pois vai depender das configurações feitas. Usar o `IIS Manager` tb pode ser bem útil :)